# Cannot pass data from dart to swift

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I try to pass these data of key 'data' and 'key' to swift side but it keeps telling me not found the params:

> flutter: PlatformException(INVALID_ARGUMENT, Parameter 'data' is missing or invalid, null, null)

I provide all the 'data' and 'key' params with the correct data types:

```
import 'package:flutter_key_generator/flutter_key_generator.dart';

void encrypt() async {
 try {
  final data = <int>[1, 2, 3];
  final key =
    await FlutterKeyGenerator.generateSymmetricKey(256);

  if (key != null) {
    final sealedBox = await NativeSide.encrypt(data, key);

    print(sealedBox);
  }
 } catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Invoke native side:

```
@override
Future<List<int>?> encrypt(List<int> data, List<int> key) async {
  final data = await methodChannel.invokeMethod<List<int>>('encrypt', { 'data': data, 'key': key });
  return data;
}
```

Swift side:

```
public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
  guard let args = call.arguments as? [String: Any] else {
      result(FlutterError(
          code: "CAUGHT_ERROR",
          message:"Invalid arguments",
          details: nil))
      return
  }
  
  do {
    switch call.method {
    case "encrypt":
        try self.encrypt(args: args, result:result)
    default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
      result(FlutterError(
          code: "CAUGHT_ERROR",
          message:"\(error.domain), \(error.code), \(error.description)",
          details: nil))
  } catch {
      result(FlutterError(
          code: "CAUGHT_ERROR",
          message:"\(error)",
          details: nil))
  }
}

private func encrypt(args: [String: Any], result: @escaping FlutterResult) throws {
        do {
            guard let data = (args["data"] as? FlutterStandardTypedData)?.data else {
                result(parameterError(name: "data"))
                return
            }
            guard let key = (args["key"] as? FlutterStandardTypedData)?.data else {
                result(parameterError(name: "key"))
                return
            }

            let sealed = try self.encryptData(plainData: data, key: key)
        } catch CryptoError.runtimeError(let errorMessage) {
            result(FlutterError(code: "InvalidArgumentError", message: errorMessage.localizedLowercase, details: nil))
        } catch {
            result(FlutterError(code: "EncryptionError", message:"Failed to encrypt: " + error.localizedDescription, details: nil))
        }
    }


private func parameterError(name: String) -> FlutterError {
    return FlutterError(code: "INVALID_ARGUMENT", message: "Parameter '\(name)' is missing or invalid", details: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

I have to convert List< int > to Uint8List before passing to native.